# Vim template/skeleton with folding

Tags: folding

I currently have a skeleton file so that whenever I create a new .cpp file, it copies the c++_template.cpp to the new file. I'm using this line in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r ~/workspace_c++/c++_template.cpp
```

I would like it to also copy the foldings. Is that possible?

Comment: You could embed folds in the comments of your template, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Tumbler41 I could do that if there are no other solution, but I would prefer to not embed the folds in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Folding will be copied if it's reproducible. If you're using `marker`, `indent`, `syntax` or `expr` folding methods, it should be reproducible automatically.

If you're using `manual`, well, it means your template expander plugin will need to interpret some information and use it to fold manually.

I never though about it, but I guess it should be possible to register such a behaviour in [my fork of mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template). In it I can register post-expansion hooks -- that I mainly use to add missing import/include statements. If in that hooks we create manual folds. It should work. The tricky part would be the extraction of the final line numbers to call `:l1,l2fold`.

Something like the following will work in simple cases  -- if you start to mix this with other hooks (to automate the inclusion of headers for instance), it'll quite likely require more wiring.

```
MuT: let s:fold_start = s:Line()
for (auto&& <+e+> : <+container+>) {
   <+code+>
}
MuT: let s:fold_end = s:Line() - 1
VimL: call s:AddPostExpandCallback('execute(s:fold_start.",".s:fold_end."fold")')
```

Regarding the syntax used here.

- `<+` and `+>` delimit placeholders. Mu-template will try to evaluate it's content, otherwise they are inserted as placeholders
- lines starting with `:VimL` are interpreted as Vim commands (that get interpreted with the `:execute` command)
- lines starting with `:MuT` are interpreted by mu-template engine, I use them to conditionally decide what to do, in this is case to define a variable that'll get automatically undefined at the end of the expansion.
- all the `s:` functions are helper functions already implemented in mu-template that we can use to define more complex template/snippets: `s:Line()` returns the line number where the current line in the template line will be actually inserted/expanded ; `s:AddPostExpandCallback()` registers a hook that'll get executed after the expansion has been completed.
- otherwise, the text we type is directly inserted when the template file is expanded.

Comment: I'm currently using manual folds and I have no template expander plugin, I'm just using the line in my question above. Is your code for your fork of mu-template? I don't understand haw it works, can you explain?

Comment: Indeed this is a skeleton for mu-template. It has a few syntaxic elements that permits to do much mote than just inserting raw text. I'll need to check the exact syntax, I can't promise right now that it'll work.